# selenium python download many parts file and stop

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have problem on automation on selenium firefox click action,  even though I have use
WebDriverWait with some time delay.  The zip file seemed to be downloaded but I can
only see many ".part" file there.  I use Ubuntu 22.04 / Firefox v.116 / Python 10 / Selenium 4

Are there any suggestions ? Here is my snippet of the download zip file:

```
def test_autoClick(self):
        '''
        '''
        site_url= 'PO_DROPBOX_URL'  # it is a link to show all button to download zip 
        ftpdir='/tmp'
        app_type='application/zip'
        timeWait=10
        
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
       
        options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", ftpdir)
        options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", app_type)#, application/force-download")
        options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/force-download")#, application/force-download")
        
        options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone",False)
        #options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
        #need set argument as headless
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        #options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        #options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        
        service=Service(log_path=os.path.devnull)
          
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)   

        browser.get(site_url)
        landing_page=browser.current_url 
        if not landing_page:
            print("error getting current utl")
            
        print(f' now i have title {browser.title} \n current url={landing_page}')
        button_xpath="//button[@aria-label='Download']"
        
        download=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_xpath )))
        download.click()
        wait=WebDriverWait(browser,timeWait)
        print('click & wait until it is done...')
        
        try: 
            at_least_oneZip = lambda x: len(x("{0}/*.zip*".format(ftpdir))) > 0
            print(f'do i have len of zip {at_least_oneZip}')
            WebDriverWait(glob.glob, timeWait).until(at_least_oneZip)
            print(f'web driver waits')
            
            no_parts = lambda x: len(x("{0}/*.part".format(ftpdir))) == 0
            WebDriverWait(glob.glob , timeWait).until(no_parts)
        
        except Exception as ex:
            
            bSuccess=0
            message=f' Error fetching file as {ex}'
            print(message)
```

When I run it, it seemed to try downloading but I only get a lot of .part files